# Formtastic radio button issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have the following code in my views

```
<%= semantic_form_for @instance do |f| %> <!-- formtastic gem form creation -->
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :foo, :label => "dType", as: :radio, collection: [ ["val1", false], ["val2", false] ] %>
    <%# strange bug omitting first letter of label %>
    <br>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.buttons do %>
    <%= f.commit_button %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Two issues.  First, I'm getting a strange bug that's omitting the first letter of the label.  Second, you have to click at least twice on a button (other than the first button) to get that button selected. Thanks in advance

Rails 3.1.1 and Formtastic 2.0.2

Comment: May not solve your problem, but: if `type` field is not being used for STI (Single Table Inheritance), I suggest you name it something other than `type`.

Comment: @Zabba yea I realized that and corrected it, thanks I edited my question to reflect the change

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing hash syntaxes... you start out using classic Ruby hashrocket style (:eg => this), but then you throw in a JSON-style (as: :radio). Pick one and be consistent.